# Splitting a number into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Alright so I'm trying to completely split a number into an Array. So for example:

```
var num = 55534;
var arr = []; <- I would want the Array to look like this [5,5,5,3,4]
```

Basically i want to to completely split the number apart and place each Number into its own element of the array. Usually in the past i would just convert the number into a string then use the `.split()` function. This is how i use to do it:

```
num += "";
var arr = num.split("");
```

But this time i actually need to use these numbers, so they can not be strings. What would you guys say be the way of doing this?

Update, after the edit for some reason my code is crashing every run:

```
function DashInsert(num) { 

  num += "";
  var arr = num.split("").map(Number); // [9,9,9,4,6]
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] % 2 === 1){
    arr.splice(i,0,"-");
    }// odd
  }
  return arr.join(""); 

}
```

Comment: Your code is adding an extra element, "-", to the array every iteration (`arr.splice(i, 0, "-")` deletes zero elements and then adds "-" at position `i`). Hence it will never finish the iteration—your `for` loop is infinite. Note that it is reading the same element over and over, because the added "-" means that the element it was reading is shifted over one index, and will be read again next iteration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String(55534).split("").map(Number)
```

...will handily do your trick.

Comment: Looks great, looks like after the edit every time i run my code it crashes

Comment: @user3890432 Crashes? What Javascript interpreter are you using, and what exception is being thrown?

Comment: Works great in Chrome 36

Comment: @Fengyang Wang I've just been using codeacademy.com to compile it. It just seems to freeze up the window when ran.

Comment: @user3890432 There seems to be an infinite loop in your code, but this is not related to the array itself, but instead your `for` loop. See the comment on the original post.

Answer (score 4):

You can do what you already did, and map a number back:

```
55534..toString().split('').map(Number)
//^ [5,5,5,3,4]
```

Comment: Why is the double `..` required? I haven't seen that before. Without it I get an unexpected token error

Comment: Because numbers can have decimals, so you need to disambiguate the expression.

Comment: `('' + 55534)` is a lot less to type though. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'll do it like bellow

```
var num = 55534;
var arr = num.toString().split(''); //convert string to number & split by ''
var digits = arr.map(function(el){return +el}) //convert each digit to numbers
console.log(digits); //prints [5, 5, 5, 3, 4]
```

Basically I'm converting each string into numbers, you can just pass `Number` function into map also.